# In CSS, want to override my a:link and a:hover directives to for a specific span

Tags: css

This will probably be a softball for you CSS folks...

I have a site like this:

```
<div id="header">
<span class="myheader">This is the name of my awesome site!!!!</span>
</div> 
<div id="content">whole bunch of other stuff</div>
<div="sidemenu"><ul><li>something</li><li>something else</li></ul>
<div id="footer">Some footer stuff will go here....</div>
```

In my css I have some directives to format the hyperlinks:

```
a:link { text-decoration: none; color : #ff6600; border: 0px; -moz-outline-style: none;}
a:active { text-decoration: underline; color : #ff6600; border: 0px; -moz-outline-style: none;}
a:visited { text-decoration: none; color : #ff6600; border: 0px; -moz-outline-style: none;}
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color : #000; border: 0px; -moz-outline-style: none;} 
a:focus { outline: none;-moz-outline-style: none;}
```

Now here is the problem.  In my header I have some text that is a link, but I do not want to to format it like all the other links in the site.  So basically I want my a:link, a:hover, etc to ignore anything in the "header" div.  How can I do this?  Assume I need to override this for that div/span?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use syntax like this..

```
a:link { text-decoration: none; color : #ff6600; border: 0px; -moz-outline-style: none;}
a:active { text-decoration: underline; color : #ff6600; border: 0px; -moz-outline-style: none;}
a:visited { text-decoration: none; color : #ff6600; border: 0px; -moz-outline-style: none;}
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color : #000; border: 0px; -moz-outline-style: none;} 
a:focus { outline: none;-moz-outline-style: none;}
```

Then using css inheritance principles you can create more specific rules for links inside the `#header` element and override any of the properties you like.

```
#header a:link {  text-decoration: underline; color : #000;  }
#header a:visited {  text-decoration: underline; color : #000;  }
```

Read about [CSS inheritance](http://simplebits.com/notebook/2003/04/15/css-inheritance/)

Answer (score 3):

try #header a:link {}, #header a:active {} etc.